# Demoiselle 2.4.0: Erro ao executar teste com JUnit

Tags: java, demoiselle, injeção-de-dependência, junit, jndi

Tenho um projeto construído a partir do arquétipo do **Demoiselle** para **Maven**. A aplicação gerada é aquela que exemplifica o Demoiselle, contendo um cadastro de *bookmarks*.

O programador que gerou a revisão zero da aplicação não mais se encontra acessível. Esta aplicação foi alterada para implementar diversos cadastros específicos, deixando de ser a aplicação exemplo para se tornar uma aplicação própria do nosso domínio de negócio.

O objetivo agora é adicionar funcionalidades e para a implementação de tais, fazer uso de TDD para primeiramente escrever os casos de teste e depois o código da aplicação em si (é uma aplicação legada, onde o TDD **não** foi utilizado em sua gênese).

Ao adicionar o primeiríssimo caso de teste, colocado abaixo, recebo uma *exception stack*. Os detalhes estão colocados abaixo.

O caso de teste é o seguinte:

```
package br.ufpr.sap.hibernate.tests;
// imports diversos
@RunWith(DemoiselleRunner.class)
public class AlunoRepositorioTests {
    @Inject
    AlunoRepository alunos;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
    @Test
    public void shouldSelecionarUmAlunoESeusObjetosRelacionados() {
        // Preparar
        Long idAluno = 31106L;

        // Executar
        Aluno aluno = alunos.itemPorId(idAluno);

        // Avaliar
        assertNotNull(aluno);
    }
}
```

As exceções recebidas são estão abaixo. A lista de chamadas foi recortada para facilitar a leitura.

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.EntityManagerFactoryProducer.loadPersistenceUnits() on br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.EntityManagerFactoryProducer@68de8813
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:400)
        ... muitas chamadas
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        ... muitas chamadas
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:398)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.DemoiselleException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: gd0] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.EntityManagerFactoryProducer.loadPersistenceUnits(EntityManagerFactoryProducer.java:107)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: gd0] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
        ... muitas chamadas
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.EntityManagerFactoryProducer.loadPersistenceUnits(EntityManagerFactoryProducer.java:105)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:jboss/env/jdbc/gd]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:92)
        ... muitas chamadas
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 101 more
```

O que está faltando?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o probelma está na configuração do ambiente para que AlunoRepository.itemPorId possa funcionar. Se você remover esta chamada funciona?

Pode ser que o persistence.xml que o seu teste está usando esteja tentando fazer um bind JNDI para um InitialContext nulo, visto que a aplicação de teste não roda no servidor de aplicação.

Para isso os testes precisam redefinir a configuração estabelecendo a conexão com o banco de dados diretamente via JDBC. A aplicação "bookmark" gerada pelo arquétipo demoiselle-jsf-jpa já traz um exemplo pronto no arquivo [src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml](https://github.com/demoiselle/framework/blob/master/archetype/jsf-jpa/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml). Este irá sobrepor o persistence.xml da sua aplicação que se encontra em [src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml](https://github.com/demoiselle/framework/blob/master/archetype/jsf-jpa/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml).

Caso esteja tudo desta forma e mesmo assim o problema continue, tente rodar os testes pela linha de comando com o Maven diretamente. Se funcionar, o problema está na IDE.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Para evitar o problema, basta não realizar a injeção do repositório `alunos`, simplesmente comentando a anotação `@Inject`. Isso sugere para mim que o problema não esta relacionado com o repositório em si ou com o que ocorre dentro dele, mas especificamente com a tentativa de injetar o repositório no caso de teste.

Comment: Realizei testes com o JUnit em outros projetos não baseados em Demoiselle e eles executam sem problema. Estes outros testes apresentam um JUnit *runner* simples que encontrei na Internet para suportar a injeção de dependências e a produção do `EntityManager` quando necessário. Assim, diante disto, me parece que o problema está, de alguma forma, relacionado com o Demoiselle.